# Rails delete the parent model, but still access the children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have customers and invoices. The users can delete customers, but not invoices.

The problem is when a customer is deleted I can no longer do

```
invoice.customer.name
```

Because customer is nil.

I have some solutions on the drawing board

1. Save some info about the customer on the invoice instance when the
   invoice is made.
2. Not deleting the customer, but hide it from the user with a boolean
   field. That way the customer instance is still around.

I know this question might be closed because the answers might be opinionated. Rails is very opinionated on almost everything. On this problem, I have never seen a opinion, so:

What is the rails best practice in this case?

(If you have a better solution I'd like to see it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to set up a deleted_at flag, I'd recommend using the paranoia gem.

https://github.com/radar/paranoia

It is exactly what your second option is and implements all the scopes that you might need.

Comment: +1 for paranoia, seems a nice little gem i didn't know about thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I also have the Firm class. It `has_many :customers, :dependent => :destroy`. Do you know how paranoia behaves when I delete a firm with the `acts_as_paranoid` call in the customer class.

Comment: paranoia is only 140 lines long so I would encourage you to read it to understand the mechanics behind it, https://github.com/radar/paranoia/blob/master/lib/paranoia.rb, it seems Rails would delete the firm but set the deleted_at on the customers.

Answer (score 1):

Your second solution seems to best IMO.

Rather than deleting the customer, introduce a DELETED flag on the customer database (then add it as a default_scope to ignore customers with DELETED = true)

this way you can leave the relationships intact. if you have loads and loads of customers, you might need to think about an archiving mechansim, but I wouldn't worry about that.